# How to get a sinus like modulo pattern

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

I'm trying to get a nice up and down animation going on my website using javascript, but I need a sequence like this:

`0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 ...`

But module which I tend to use for repetitive actions only gives me:

`0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 ...`

How can I get a circular pattern, for example from a `i++` variable.

I tried applying a sinus wave for example.

Comment: You probably don't want all the numbers to be integers... Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to want is a triangle wave. Try this out:

```js
var period = 8,
    amplitude = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  console.log(
    amplitude * Math.abs(
      2*(i/period - Math.floor(i/period + 1/2))
    )
  )
}
```

Here's a version which uses the modulus operator:

```js
var period = 8,
    amplitude = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  console.log(
    (2 * amplitude/period) * (
      Math.abs(((i + period/2) % period) - period/2)
    )
  )
}
```

Both of these work on the principle that you can create a triangle wave by taking the absolute value of a sawtooth wave. In the first we use `Math.floor` to create a sawtooth wave and in the second we use `%`.

Comment: I should avoid saying just thanks in comments, but I like to just thank you for this :). Awesome sawtooth wave!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
"use strict"
for (let i=0;i<20;i+=0.25) { // step size
  console.log(
    Math.round( //integers only
      Math.abs( //positives
        Math.sin(i)*4 //sin goes from 0 to 1, so if your peak is 4...
      )
    )
  );
}
```